# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'reset_default_graph'

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I have installed tensorflow version r0.11.

In my file name `cartpole.py` I have imported `tensorflow`:

```
 import tensorflow as tf
```

and use it:

```
 tf.reset_default_graph()
```

Trying to run my project in PyCharm I get this error:

```
in <module>
tf.reset_default_graph()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'reset_default_graph'
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Could you provide some more code? I've got a feeling you might not have imported things correctly

Comment: Or perhaps you may have named a file `tensorflow.py` in the project

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You normally import `tensorflow` by writing,

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

It's possible that you have named a file in your project `tensorflow.py` and the `import` statement is importing from this file.

Alternatively, you can try this,

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
ops.reset_default_graph()
```

Comment: I tried this your tip. But this occured:   Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1
I've used:
   
    pip install --upgrade setuptools
or
   
     easy_install -U setuptools
but nothing helped.

Comment: my file name is *cartpole.py*
I've imported: 
     *import tensorflow as tf*
and use
*tf.reset_default_graph()*

Comment: You should add these details to your question. I think it's a PyCharm specific issue. Have you tried opening a python terminal in a different folder and typing `import tensorflow as tf; tf.reset_default_graph()` ?

Comment: i've solved an issue, thanks! 
the problem was in python version. it was running 2.7 by default, when my project was running on version 3.5.2
it works well when you run project like *python3* and then use *tensoreflow*, also i made python version 3.5.2 by default

Comment: @magnp I would suggest that you write your own answer for that. Using Python 3 helped me too.

Comment: This suggestion didn't work for me on my colab session, since I already was using python3, but the suggestions below with `from tensorflow.keras import ...` worked

Comment: This is a more sensible way of doing it rather than reverting the compatibility with version 1

Answer (score 90):

This function is deprecated. 
Use `tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()` instead.

*Update*
This is not the only function to be out of date. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55872941/8205650) for release notes and a conversion script.

Comment: that is exactly what the accepted answer says, so your answer is redundant

Comment: Yeah you are right the accepted answer is not actually addressing the problem this is the actual answer

Answer (score 9):

I have tried and successfully removed the attribute error

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPool2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

classifier = Sequential()
```

Answer (score 9):

Actually, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55143329/13572251) will resolve all TF 1.x related issues.

Get TF 1.x like behaviour in TF 2.0 by using this:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

Answer (score 5):

Change your import to tensorflow.keras
For example
    From keras import Sequential
to
    From tensorflow.keras import Sequential

Answer (score 5):

Change:

```
import keras.<something>.<something>
```

to:

```
import tensorflow.keras.<something>.<something>
```

Where 'something' is the module you want to import

Answer (score 2):

I am adding this text, so that, people like me - who might have old code from 2018, failing with tensorflow latest version.

My situation was that, in 2018, the versions being used were 1.x
The latest, as of writing this post , is 2.x

So, when I ran the code stored in google colab, it actually failed with the error that tensorflow.contrib module not found

For this, you can do the following magic mentioned in :

https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/tensorflow_version.ipynb#scrollTo=NeWVBhf1VxlH

Basically in your jupyter notebook cell, just run in a separate cell at the top

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
```

This will switch your tensorflow version to 1.15.2 I guess

And then your old code will still work like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

This also may caused you run your code in the wrong environment.

I install tensorflow-gpu in my `~/tensorflow` virtualenv.

I can run the python3 code.py in the env with `source ./tensorflow/bin/activate`

But whenI ran python3 code.py in the env `~` without virtualenv, I **sometimes** may came to issues like

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'reset_default_graph'

or

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'

and some others

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing directly from keras

from keras.layers import Input

Import from tensorflow

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input

I got this issue twice and the above one solved my issue

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Downloading binary version of TensorFlow solved my problem.

```sh
$ pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade "<URL>"
```

**Select right binary URL according to your system from below.**
https://github.com/lakshayg/tensorflow-build

Comment: Thanks! This solution of upgrading tensorflow removed the error for me.. But I have 'uninstall'ed and re-'install'ed instead of --upgrade option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tf 2.0 beta make sure that all your keras imports are tensorflow.keras... any keras imports will pickup the standard keras package that assumes tensorflow 1.4.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, InputLayer
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

Replace

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

By

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```