# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'InteractiveSession'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow from Source on Ubuntu 16.10 environment. Everything went smooth but now on compiling a program, it shows the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ff.py", line 3, in <module>
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'InteractiveSession'
```

Didn't find any post related to this. Could someone please help?

Comment: Make sure you don't have a file named `tensorflow.py`

Comment: Does `tf.Session` do anything?

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3369

Comment: @chris_anderson No, it doesn't

Comment: @YaoZhang the thread refers to the answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37383812/tensorflow-module-object-has-no-attribute-placeholder which says to remove file named tensorflow.py if any but I do not have such file in my case

Comment: Are you able to use tf.Session? Does it produce the same error?

Comment: [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'reset_default_graph'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51120550/6521116)

Answer (score 23):

```
sess=tf.compat.v1.InteractiveSession()
```

Use above line instead of `sess = tf.InteractiveSession()` line, if you are using tesorflow 2.0.0 version

Answer (score 11):

The error causes from Tensorflow version. When you've install v2.x and try to use v1.x, you'll get this error. To avoid this,

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tfc
```

Use **tfc** instead of **tf** when you get the same error on the other functions like:

```
sess = tfc.InteractiveSession()

my_tensor = tfc.random_uniform((4, 4), 0, 1)
print(my_tensor)
```

Answer (score 1):

Today I got the same error after instaling `tenserflow-serving-api`. I installed tensorflow again and everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Use the magic line:

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
```