# Trouble running tf.InteractiveSession() in Jupyter

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter, interactive

I am having trouble running `tf.InteractiveSession()` in Jupyter and I am not sure how to amend it. I am a beginner so I would appreciate some guidance!

Inputting this code here:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x = tf.constant([[1, 2]])
negMatrix = tf.negative(x)

result = negMatrix.eval()
print(result)

sess.close()
```

Produces this error message:

```
**AttributeError**: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'InteractiveSession'
```

Comment: What version of tensorflow and jupyter are you using?

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41333798/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-interactivesession) answer you question ?

Comment: Let me know if it's solved using tensorflow v 1.13.2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'InteractiveSession'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41333798/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-interactivesession)

Answer (score 0):

Using Tensorflow 2.6.0. you can import tf.compat.v1.InteractiveSession()

**Sample working code below**

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
sess = tf.compat.v1.InteractiveSession()
a = tf.constant(5.0)
b = tf.constant(6.0)
c = a * b
# We can just use 'c.eval()' without passing 'sess'
print(c.eval())
sess.close()
```

**Output**

```
30.0
```