# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'reset_default_graph'

Tags: python, tensorflow

While using U-Net in tensorflow, using the command:
 `net = unet.Unet(nx=128, ny=128, layers=3, features_root=64, channels=1, n_class=2)` gives attribute error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'reset_default_graph'` . There is no tensorflow.py file which is being imported by default as in few similar issues I came across.

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you do `import tensorflow` and `import inspect` and see what's the output of `inspect.getsourcefile(tensorflow)`

Comment: /home/mojo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py

Comment: Perhaps the issue is in the `unet` module? If you add the code that Yaroslav suggested to the file containing the `unet.Unet` implementation, do you get a different result?

Comment: Yes the result is different and is /home/mojo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tf_unet-0.1.0-py2.7.egg/tf_unet/unet.py

Comment: [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'reset_default_graph'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51120550/6521116)