# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Graph'

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, tensorflow

I am writing the following code in Jupyter notebook.

```
import tensorflow as tf
g = tf.Graph()
```

And I encounter the following error while executing this simple code.

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Graph'

If I execute the same from the console. It works. Any idea what's happening here.

**More information:**(test is my virtualenv)

ipython, jupyter, python version:

```
(test) xingzhou@xingzhou008:~/tensorflow$ which ipython3
/home/xingzhou/tensorflow/test/bin/ipython3
(test) xingzhou@xingzhou008:~/tensorflow$ which jupyter
/home/xingzhou/tensorflow/test/bin/jupyter
(test) xingzhou@xingzhou008:~/tensorflow$ which python3
/home/xingzhou/tensorflow/test/bin/python3
```

Execute from Console:

```
(test) xingzhou@xingzhou008:~/tensorflow$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> g = tf.Graph()
>>> type(g)
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph'>
>>>
```

Comment: [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'reset_default_graph'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51120550/6521116)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you haven't called any of your python files as 'tensorflow.py'

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by restarting Jupyter Notebook kernel. It's weird.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution worked for me.
From `anaconda navigator` first go to environments and create a tensorflow environment like this image

[image]

I named it `tensorflow`. Then from the right select all from the drop down menu and search for tensorflow.

[image]

Select it and hit apply. It will download some additional packages along with tensorflow. When you are done, select tensorflow from home and you should be good to go. Here it works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if TensorFlow is installed in Anaconda/Environments. If not, just search and install. Then try to run g=tf.Graph() again. It worked for me.