# Tensorflow 2.0 - AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

When I am executing the command `sess = tf.Session()` in Tensorflow 2.0 environment, I am getting an error message as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'
```

> System Information:

- OS Platform and Distribution: Windows 10
- Python Version: 3.7.1
- Tensorflow Version: 2.0.0-alpha0 (installed with pip)

> Steps to reproduce:
>
> Installation:

1. pip install --upgrade pip
2. **pip install tensorflow==2.0.0-alpha0**
3. pip install keras
4. pip install numpy==1.16.2

> Execution:

1. Execute command: import tensorflow as tf
2. Execute command: sess = tf.Session()

Comment: Weird. I think it is not due to the TF version, but the complete TF installation is broken. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18538#issuecomment-403211069

Comment: TensorFlow 2.0 works around [functions, not sessions](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180918-functions-not-sessions-20.md). I think the initial idea was to keep `tf.Session` at least initially, but looking at [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf) it seems it has finally have been scraped completely.

Comment: Oh it seems you can still access it through [`tf.compat.v1.Session`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/Session).

Comment: @DmytroPrylipko I tried it before creating this question. It did not work for me.

Answer (score 395, accepted):

According to `TF 1:1 Symbols Map`, in TF 2.0 you should use `tf.compat.v1.Session()` instead of `tf.Session()`

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FLFJLzg7WNP6JHODX5q8BDgptKafq_slHpnHVbJIteQ/edit#gid=0

To get TF 1.x like behaviour in TF 2.0 one can run

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

but then one cannot benefit of many improvements made in TF 2.0. For more details please refer to the migration guide 
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate

Comment: Using 
```import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```
gives me an error `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.compat.v1' has no attribute 'contrib'`

Comment: Found this in TF 2.0 migration documentation `It is still possible to run 1.X code, unmodified (except for contrib), in TensorFlow 2.0`

Comment: Which TF version are you using when you get the `tensorflow_core` has no attribute error?

Comment: I have downloaded a few notebooks and I was facing these issues having imported statements at the top as mentioned in the answer helped me get rid of the irritating error.

Comment: How do I evaluate static `.pb` graph in TF2 then? Only through using tf1-feature like `tf.compat.v1.Session()`. In TF2 you're supposed to use eager mode always and no `.pb`?

Answer (score 115):

TF2 runs Eager Execution by default, thus removing the need for Sessions. If you want to run static graphs, the more proper way is to use `tf.function()` in TF2. While Session can still be accessed via `tf.compat.v1.Session()` in TF2, I would discourage using it. It may be helpful to demonstrate this difference by comparing the difference in hello worlds:

TF1.x hello world:

```
import tensorflow as tf
msg = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(msg))
```

TF2.x hello world:

```
import tensorflow as tf
msg = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
tf.print(msg)
```

For more info, see [Effective TensorFlow 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/effective_tf2)

Comment: Is there non-eager mode in TF2? Or eager mode is only suggested mode of execution? What if I want to have static `.pb` file in TF2? Is it possible? How do I evaluate it then in TF2?

Answer (score 41):

I faced this problem when I first tried python after installing `windows10 + python3.7(64bit) + anacconda3 + jupyter notebook.`

I solved this problem by refering to "https://vispud.blogspot.com/2019/05/tensorflow200a0-attributeerror-module.html"

I agree with

> I believe "Session()" has been removed with TF 2.0.

I inserted two lines. One is `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` and the other is `sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()`

My Hello.py is as follows:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()

print(sess.run(hello))
```

Comment: I would rather say that in TF 2.0 `Session()` has been moved not removed. The *need of using* `Session()` has been removed.

Answer (score 7):

For `TF2.x`, you can do like this.

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    hello = tf.constant('hello world')
    print(sess.run(hello))
```

`>>> b'hello world`

Answer (score 4):

If this is your code, the correct solution is to rewrite it to not use `Session()`, since that's no longer necessary in TensorFlow 2

If this is just code you're running, you can downgrade to TensorFlow 1 by running

```
pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0
```

*(or whatever the [latest version of TensorFlow 1](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#history) is)*

Comment: After `1.15.x` there should be no other `1.x` version of TF, unless some patches will come, but no improvements.

Answer (score 4):

Tensorflow 2.x support's Eager Execution by default hence Session is not supported.

Answer (score 4):

For Tensorflow 2.0 and later, try this.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

a = tf.constant(5)
b = tf.constant(6)
c = tf.constant(7)
d = tf.multiply(a,b)
e = tf.add(c,d)
f = tf.subtract(a,c)

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
  outs = sess.run(f)
  print(outs)
```

Answer (score 4):

To work with TensorFlow 2.x, you should use tf.compat.v1.Session instead of tf.Session.

Answer (score 2):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
```

this code will show an Attribute error on version 2.x

to use version 1.x code in version 2.x

try this

```py
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
sess = tf.Session()
```

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
```

if there is an error, use the following

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
import tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same problem when I first tried Google Colab after updating **Windows 10**. Then I changed and inserted two lines,

- `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()`
- `sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()`

As a result, everything goes OK

Answer (score 0):

Using Anaconda + Spyder (Python 3.7)

[code]

```
import tensorflow as tf
valor1 = tf.constant(2)
valor2 = tf.constant(3)
type(valor1)
print(valor1)
soma=valor1+valor2
type(soma)
print(soma)
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
with sess:
    print(sess.run(soma))
```

[console]

```
import tensorflow as tf
valor1 = tf.constant(2)
valor2 = tf.constant(3)
type(valor1)
print(valor1)
soma=valor1+valor2
type(soma)
Tensor("Const_8:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
Out[18]: tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor

print(soma)
Tensor("add_4:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()

with sess:
    print(sess.run(soma))
5
```

Answer (score 0):

TF v2.0 supports Eager mode vis-a-vis Graph mode of v1.0. Hence, tf.session() is not supported on v2.0. Hence, would suggest you to rewrite your code to work in Eager mode.

Comment: Does TF2 support non-eager mode at all? Or non-eager is just tf1 feature? How do I evaluate `.pb` graphs in tf2 then?

Answer (score 0):

**Same problem occurred for me**

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello World ') 
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()    *//I got the error on this step when I used 
                                   tf.Session()*
sess.run(hello)
```

Try replacing it with `tf.compact.v1.Session()`

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it while some imports like,

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
import numpy as np
```

Then I suggest you to follow these steps,
 NOTE: For TensorFlow2 and for CPU Process only 
Step 1:  Tell your code to act as if the compiler is TF1 and disable TF2 behavior, use the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

Step 2: While importing libraries, remind your code that it has to act like TF1, yes EVERYTIME.

```
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
import numpy as np
```

Conclusion: This should work, let me know if something goes wrong, also if it is GPU, then do mention to add a backend code for keras. Also, TF2 does not support session there is a separate understanding for that and has been mentioned on TensorFlow, the link is:
 
[TensorFlow Page for using Sessions in TF2](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/Session) 
 
Other major TF2 changes have been mentioned in this link, it is long but please go through it, use Ctrl+F for assistance. Link,
 
[Effective TensorFlow 2 Page Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/effective_tf2)

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy as you think, running TF 1.x with TF 2.x environment I found some errors and need to reviews of some variables usages when I fixed the problems on the neuron networks on the Internet. Transform to TF 2.x is better idea.
( Easier and adaptive )

#### TF 2.X

```
while not done:
    next_obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action) 
        env.render()
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(
            img,
            data_format=None,
            scale=True
    )
    img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
    predictions = model_self_1.predict(img_array) ### Prediction

### Training: history_highscores = model_highscores.fit(batched_features, epochs=1 ,validation_data=(dataset.shuffle(10))) # epochs=500 # , callbacks=[cp_callback, tb_callback]
```

#### TF 1.X

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver()
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(savedir + '\\invader_001'))
    train_loss, _ = sess.run([loss, training_op], feed_dict={X:o_obs, y:y_batch, X_action:o_act})
    
    for layer in mainQ_outputs: 
                model.add(layer)
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten() )
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
        predictions = model.predict(obs) ### Prediction

    
### Training: summ = sess.run(summaries, feed_dict={X:o_obs, y:y_batch, X_action:o_act})
```