# Converting Alexnet from Tensorflow 1.x to Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to train Alexnet on a test harness and I am passing the harness the model definition (which is written in TF1.X). All parts of the test harness are functioning properly, but when I pass the model for training I am met with

```
module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'
```

since my model definition is old and the test harness is running the latest-and-greatest TF2.0 (tensorflow             2.0.0a0).

The posts I've found that address this problem are the following:

[Tensorflow 2.0 - AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55142951/tensorflow-2-0-attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-session)

[Module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870127/module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-contrib)

but none of them actually solve the issue.

**What I've tried:**

- A recommendation above suggests I upgrade my TF1.X code to TF2.0 by passing files or folders to `tf_upgrade_v2` as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade), but from the release notes (and actually running it) I find that `.contrib` is the only library whose conversion isn't supported.
- The other recommendation ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57629649/6684114)) was that I could achieve the same results by modifying environmental variables using the `os` module, but the test harness I'm working in doesn't allow me to access environmental variables, so this avenue won't work.
- From the TF website I found [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#a_note_on_slim_contriblayers) which describes a method for converting `tf.contrib.slim` into TF2.0 (seemed promising) but given their proposed solution of `tf.contrib.slim` > `v1.layers` > `keras` this will involve a significant amount of work on my end so I would like to exhaust any other available options before going down this rabbit hole.

What are my options for rewriting Alexnet in TF2.0?

Comment: What do you mean by model definition? It's architecture? If so, have you tried saving the weights of your TF1 model, recreating a model (in TF2) with the same architecture and then loading the weights? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#load_weights

Comment: Yes, it is the model architecture I'm referring to. It uses functions like `tf.contrib.slim`, which I am unable to rewrite in TF2.0 (without significant effort, as above).

Comment: @EduardoBarrera If you found any working solution please share it. Thanks

Comment: @SiamakSiaSoft I found a PyTorch implementation that my test harness worked with, and scrapped trying to convert from TF1.X to TF2.0. Sorry is this isn't a solution on your end!