# how to fix : module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, data-science

```
import tensorflow as tf
a=tf.constant(2)
b=tf.constant(3)
c=a+b
sess=tf.Session(c)
sess.run()
```

I got the error message module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'

Comment: which Tensorflow version are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorflow 2.0 - AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55142951/tensorflow-2-0-attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-session)

Answer (score 5):

From the official doc try the following:

```
# Build a graph.
a = tf.constant(5.0)
b = tf.constant(6.0)
c = a * b

# Launch the graph in a session.
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()

# Evaluate the tensor `c`.
print(sess.run(c))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:

  a = tf.constant(5.0)
  b = tf.constant(6.0)
  c = tf.multiply(a, b)

  result = sess.run(c)
  print(result)
```