# When using the Deepbrain libary error message "module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use the library Deepbrain to extract brains from the entire MRIs scan I am using the code

```
def Reduce_Brain(img):
     img_data = img.get_fdata()
     prob = ext.run(img)
     print(prob)

img = nib.load('ADNI_002_S_0295.nii')
Reduce_Brain(img)
```

however, when I tried this I got the error module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session' which I found was an error to do with the wrong version of tensorflow so I then changed the library code as said in the other question (see below). but this produced more errors such as module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'

[Tensorflow 2.0 - AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55142951/tensorflow-2-0-attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-session)

https://github.com/iitzco/deepbrain

Answer (score 0):

In TF 2.x you should use `tf.compat.v1.Session()` instead of `tf.Session()`.
Take a look at [Migrate_tf2 guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/migrate_tf2) for more information

To get TF 1.x like behaviour in TF 2.0 add below code

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```